# JavaScript having trouble with using variables in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, innerhtml

I'm having a problem with this code snippet

```
document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = "<?php $query = 'select * from 
subcategory_ref where category_no = " + a +"'; 
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query); echo '<select>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$id =$row['subcategory']; $name = $row['subcategory_name']; echo '<option> test </option>';};
echo '</select>'; ?>"
```

Var a is a number corresponding to a previous drop-down box. When alert(a) is used it alerts the value of var a but the innerHTML isn't reading it properly.

The reason I know there is a problem is if we replace the the 'a' in

```
subcategory_ref where category_no = " + a +"';
```

with

```
subcategory_ref where category_no = " + 1 +"';
```

The drop-down appears and is populated with the "test" option.

The value of var a is obtained like this

```
var a = document.getElementById("category").value;
```

Category being another drop-down box

However hard-coding a number inside the variable like this also doesn't work.

```
var a = 1;
```

Any ideas? We've been stuck on this for such a long time and it's unfortunately frustrating, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That `a` is still part of the php code, so it's being interpreted by php, not by JavaScript. This, of course, assumes that all of this is inside a php file. Also, little Bobby Tables would like to have a word with you.

Comment: Is there anyway to make it so that 'a' can be interpreted by the PHP code?

Comment: Yes, don't do that in JavaScript. Pass that variable to a php script (via AJAX, for example) on the backend and do whatever you need to do from there.

Comment: Also thank you for the answer! I used this algorithm before albeit a JSP version, which is why it worked correctly back then.

Comment: Thank you so much!